# What framework combination to choose for developing Windows 8 hybrid application?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, windows, hybrid-mobile-app

I am planning to develop a hybrid application for Windows tablet. Which framework or tool I should use. Currently, I am thinking to go for PhoneGap/Sencha combinations but not 100% confident about it as I haven't got much read about this combination on Windows 8 platform (Rt/pro).

Please suggest.

Comment: Anyone here to help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneJS is a paid framework and still have some issues. I would like prepand you to use Cordova PhoneGap framework and use extension for VS2013

Also here tutorial about developing for windows http://msopentech.com/opentech-projects/apache-cordova/ and here http://blog.falafel.com/getting-started-with-cordova-and-multi-device-hybrid-app-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried Phonejs? It s pretty good.

Comment: Phonejs is a good option but doesn't support Windows(Tablet).